# Is it possible to connect an Xbox 360 wireless controller to the Xbox One's wireless receiver for PC?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

I got 2 Xbox 360 wireless controllers for my PC. I'm considering that the Xbox 360 controller won't connect to the Xbox One S receiver (meaning the 360 controller will be phased out soon and games might use a new XInput API that's incompatible with the 360 controller). Can I still do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, Xbox 360 wireless controllers need a compatible Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver. They aren't compatible with any Xbox One receivers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_accessories#Wireless_Gaming_Receiver

See **Set up a wireless controller on a Windows PC** on this page:

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/xbox-360/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-controller-for-windows-setup